# Two Kanji Radicals for "River"?

Tags: kanji, radicals

I was studying some radicals using an app and one of the radicals listed is defined as river and looks like this:

> 巛

Yet I know the kanji for river looks like:

> 川

Can anyone explain to me what the difference is?

Comment: There *is* a second kanji for river.  It is 河.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

川 is the kanji used normally for "river".
巛 (まがりがわ) is a radical, like 氵(さんずい).

When speaking about radicals, 川 and 巛 are said to be the same radical - radical 47, but only 川 is seen as both a radical and a separate kanji while 巛 is only seen as part of other kanji. For example, 山川 is a word where 川 is a whole kanji, and お巡りさん is a word with the 巛 radical (as part of 巡).

Comment: Or for example 順, which also uses the vertically straight version of 川.

Comment: You say 川 is Radical 47, but what categorization system are you referring to?